# Laravel Many to Many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a laravel application and I have the following models

1. Workshop
2. WorkshopCategory

I have 3 tables,

- workshops
- workshop_categories
- workshop_category_relation

I am trying to use eloquent to out put all my workshops, with the associated categories like the following:

```
{

"id":14,
"workshop_name":"First Workshop",
"description":"Located all over",
"categories": array: [
      0 => "wood"
      1 => "metal"
    ]

}
```

What would the best method be to achieve this? would I in my workshop model add the following:

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Workshopcategory', 'workshop_category_relation', 'workshop_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

I have added the above function to my workshop model and when I try output a workshop like the following:

```
$workshop = Workshop::FindOrFail(14);
return $workshop->categories();
```

I get the following error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
>   could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for a [Many to Many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

All you'll need to do is rename your `workshop_category_relation` table to 'workshop_category' and then your `belongsToMany` should work.

Comment: Ive updated the question as I have tried this method.

Comment: What happens when you `dd($workshop);` before you return? I'm thinking the problem is probably that you're using `categories()` instead of just `categories`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
return $workshop->categories()->get();
```

or just:

```
return $workshop->categories;
```

You'll get a `Collection` of categories related to workshop and then you can itterate over like:

```
foreach($workshop->categories as $category) {
    $category->field_name
}
```